# display variable with floatformat based on condition

Tags: django

i want to limit digits in numbers bigger than 1 by 2 digits.
i want to find out if there is a short-syntax to simplify code from
5 lines to a one liner and learn from your experience.

expected output :

```
   100.00 , 10.00 , 1.00 , 0.00000001
```

working code

```
   {% if number > 1 %}
     {{ number | floatformat:2 }}
   {% else %}
     {{ number }} 
   {% endif %}
```

im looking for a possible syntax like this pseudo code

```
   {{ number | if number > 1 floatformat:2  }}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom template filter for your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `if else` clause in one line just like this:

```
{% if number > 1 %}{{ number | floatformat:2 }}{% else %}{{ number }}{% endif %}
```

If you want something custom you can create a custom template tag:

```py
def custom_format(value):
    return "%.2f" % value if value > 1 else value
```

And then in your template you could use it like this:

```py
{{ number|custom_format }}
```

More info about custom template tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) and more info about the build-in template tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins).

Comment: thanks. regarding filters - i thought the same but wanted to make sure there is no simpler way first. thanks a lot hagyn

Comment: @scco mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you